# CSS reset interferes with a third party HTML/CSS component

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jqgrid, css-reset

I use [Eric Meyer’s CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (jQuery Grid plugin).

The reset interferes with the CSS styling of the grid, and the grid looks unacceptable.

What is the common way to solve this sort of problem (a CSS reset affects a third party component on your page)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should include Eric Meyer’s CSS reset at *the first CSS style* which you use. It's designed to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings. So it should changes browser defaults, but not any explicit settings of CSS which you use.

The only style which I find a little suspected in the "Eric Meyer’s CSS reset" is the setting

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
```

It's the only CSS style which seems have some correlation with jqGrid CSS. So I suggest that you include additional CSS

```css
.ui-jqgrid table {
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

which changes `border-collapse` inside of jqGrid. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridAndResetCSS.htm) uses the style and the results looks the same like in the grid without "Eric Meyer’s CSS reset".

Answer (score 0):

What is your reason for using the reset? I would never use one. If it's affecting your third-party stuff, and you can't give a reason for using one, get rid of it. You're probably setting values for your elements anyway and, thus, overriding the reset on top of that.

Comment: Rob, thank you! I know that there is no common opinion on whether or not CSS resets are necessary. I'll consider removing it as one of the options if I have similar problems in the future.

Comment: @Alexey It is not opinion. CSS resets are never necessary. Whether they should be used can be opinion. My opinion is you are setting everything once, and then setting everything a second time later, which makes it superfluous and slows things down. Actually, that's fact, not opinion.